# creating profile pictures with codeigniter and tank auth

Tags: image, codeigniter, profile

I've tried following step by step guide from below tutorial but upload failed :
http://www.andrewrice.org/2012/03/creating-profile-pictures-with-codeigniter-and-tank-auth/

I have successfully installed tank-auth into my codeigniter site. Please tell me how to fix this issue. Thank you.

```
**Profile Controller (/application/controllers/profile.php)**

function picture() {

    /* Loads the Tank Auth "users" model, and assigns it the alias "foo" */
    $this->load->model('tank_auth/users','foo');

    /* Gets the logged-in user's ID, from preloaded Tank Auth library */
    $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

    /* Queries profile information for the user who's logged in ...
    ... including the profile pictures (see the table structure below) */
    $data = $this->foo->get_profile_by_id($user_id);

    /* Passes that data to the header, menu, form, and footer views */
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/menu', $data);
    /* Loads the upload_form view */
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
}

function do_upload() {  

    /* Upload Settings */
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1024';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['width'] = '128';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    /* Encrypting helps prevent the file name from being discerned once its saved */
    $config['encrypt_name'] = 'TRUE';

    /* Load the CodeIgniter upload library, feed it the config from above */
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    /* Checks if the do_upload function has been successfully executed ...
    ... and if not, shows the upload form and any errors (if they exist) */
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){

    /* Loads the model (predefined database instructions, see below) ...
    ... and assigns it a nickname, I went with 'foo' */
    $this->load->model('tank_auth/users','foo');

    /* Makes the logged-in user's id a nice, clean variable */
    $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

    /* Use the model to gather all user profile information for that user_id */
    $profile_data = (array) $this->foo->get_profile_by_id($user_id);

    /* Pass that data into the data variable (for the views) */
    $data = $profile_data;

    /* Process errors if they exist */
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    /* Pass everything into the views */
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/menu', $data);
    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    /* ... if the file passes validation ... */ 
    } else { 

    /* Load the users model, assign it alias 'foo' (or whatever you want) */
    $this->load->model('tank_auth/users','foo');

    /* Assign logged-in user ID to a nice, clean variable */
    $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

    /* Assign the upload's metadata (size, dimensions, destination, etc.) ...
    ... to an array with another nice, clean variable */
    $upload = (array) $this->upload->data();

    /* Assign's the user's profile data to yet another nice, clean variable */
    $profile_data = (array) $this->foo->get_profile_by_id($user_id);

    /* Uses two upload library features to assemble the file name (the name, and extension) */
    $filename = $upload['raw_name'].$upload['file_ext'];

    /* Same with the thumbnail we'll generate, but with the suffix '_thumb' */
    $thumb = $upload['raw_name']."_thumb".$upload['file_ext'];

    /* Set the rules for the upload */
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = "./uploads/".$filename;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']     = 128;
    $config['height']   = 128;

    /* Load "image manipulation library", see CodeIgniter user guide */
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

    /* Resize the image! */
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    /* Assign upload_data to $data variable */
    $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();

    /* Assign profile_data to $data variable */
    $data['profile_data'] = $profile_data;

    /* Runs the users model (update_photo function, see below) and ...
    ... loads the location of the photo new photo into user's profile */
    $this->foo->update_photo($user_id, $filename, $thumb);

    /* Load "success" view with all the data! */
    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);

    }
}

**The Upload Form View (/application/views/upload_form.php)**

<h1>Change Profile Picture</h1>
<?php echo $error;?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('profile/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload New Picture" />undefined</form>

**User Model (/application/models/tank_auth/users.php)**
function update_photo($user_id, $filename, $thumb){
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $arr = array(
    'photo'=> $filename,
    'thumb' => $thumb
    );
    $this->db->update($this->profile_table_name, $arr);
}

**Displaying the Profile Picture (/application/views/menu.php)**

<div style='width: 128px; height: 
    <?php echo $size[1]; ?>px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: solid 1px #ccc; background: url("http://thc.fiu.edu/uploads/
    <?php echo $thumb; ?>");'/>
    <?php $size = getimagesize("http://www.yourwebsite.com/uploads/".$thumb); ?>
    <a href="/profile/picture" class='editprofile' style="display: block; width: 128px; height: 
        <?php echo $size[1]; ?>px">&nbsp;
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: I got : 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Users::get_profile_by_id() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CIX2/application/controllers/Profile.php on line 97 A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CIX2/application/controllers/Profile.php:97) Filename: core/Common.php Line Number: 569 Backtrace: A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error Message: Call to undefined method Users::get_profile_by_id() Filename: controllers/Profile.php Line Number: 97

Comment: on line 97 :  
$profile_data = (array) $this->foo->get_profile_by_id($user_id);

Comment: It's very simple user_model have not get_profile_by_id() method defined. See at your question code it's have only upload_photo()

Comment: Just go to the tutorial and check model code once again